# Getting a list of common strings with first occurance mark

Tags: windows, string, batch-file

I've got bunch of text files with some content. First I wanted to number the lines globally. Then I extracted all lines that are duplicated somewhere (occur in any of given files at least twice). But now I need to mark all of these lines with the filename and line number of the first occurrence of this line. And now the funny part - it needs to be a windows batch file, using native windows tools. That's why I've got this problem to begin with.

So, to sum it up:

I have a file **A** with unique strings/lines, each of them is said to occur at least twice in given set of files.

I need to search these files and mark all occurrences of given line from **A** file with
-file name in which the line first occured
-line number in this file

This is my code with effort to number lines and format files.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a lnum=0
if not [%1]==[] pushd %1

for /r %%F in (*.txt) do call :sub "%%F"
echo Total lines in %Files% files: %Total%
popd
exit /b 0
:Sub
set /a Cnt=0

for /f %%n in ('type %1') do (
  set /a Cnt+=1
  set /a lnum=!lnum!+1
  echo ^<!lnum!^> %%n >> %1_ln.txt && echo ^<!lnum!^> >> %1_ln.txt && echo. >> %1_ln.txt
)
set /a Total+=Cnt
set /a Files+=1
echo %1: %Cnt% lines
```

Comment: So what's the question?  What is not working in your code?

Comment: What is the "first" file? Sort by name, time ...? Including subfolders? Please tell more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set lnum=0
if not "%~1" == "" pushd %1

rem "I've got bunch of text files..." (%%F is file name)
for /r %%F in (*.txt) do call :sub "%%F"
echo Total lines in %Files% files: %lnum%
popd
exit /b 0


:Sub "filename"
set Cnt=0

rem "... with some content." (%%n is line contents)
(for /f "usebackq delims=" %%n in (%1) do (
   set /a Cnt+=1
   rem "First I wanted to number the lines globally."
   set /a lnum+=1
   echo ^<!lnum!^> %%n 
   rem "Then I extracted all lines that are duplicated somewhere" (that were defined before)
   if defined line[%%n] (
      rem "I need to mark all of these lines with the filename and line number of the first occurrence of this line."
      echo ^<!line[%%n]!^>
      echo/
   ) else (
      REM (Store the first occurrence of this line with *local* line number and filename)
      set line[%%n]=!Cnt!: %1
   )
)) > "%~PN1_ln.txt"
set /A Files+=1
echo %1: %Cnt% lines
exit /B
```

The above Batch program ignore empty lines in the input files and fail if they contain special Batch characters, like `! & < > |`; this limitation may be fixed if required.

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed. I modified it to suit my needs exactly but the base idea is the thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR /f "delims=" %%s IN (A) DO (
 SET searching=Y
 FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN (
  'dir /s /b /a-d *.txt') DO IF DEFINED searching (
  FOR /f "tokens=1delims=:" %%L IN (
   'findstr /b /e /n /l /c:"%%s" ^<"%%f"') DO IF DEFINED searching (
ECHO Line %%L IN "%%f" FOUND "%%s"
SET "searching="
 )
 )
)
```

Here's the meat of a routine that should do what you appear to be looking for - and that's as clear as mud.

It looks through the "A" file for each string in turn, assigns the string to `%%s` and sets the flag `searching`

Then it looks through the file list, assigning filenames to `%%f`

Then it executes a `findstr` to find the `/c:"%%s"` complete string `%%s` (including any spaces) in `/l` or literal mode (ie. not using regular expressions) for a line that both `/b` and `/e` begins and ends with the target (ie exactly matches) and `/n` numbers those lines.

The output of findstr will be in the format `linenumber:linecontents` so if this line is examined by the `FOR`with the option `"delims=:"` then the partion up to the first `:` is assigned to to `%%L`

So - `%%L` contains the line#, `%%f` the filename, `%%s` the string
Clearing `searching` having detected this line by setting its value to [nothing] means it's not `NOT DEFINED` hence no further lines will be reported from the current file, and no further filenames will be examined.

Now if you want to get a listing of ALL of the occurrences of the target lines, all you need to do is to REM-out the `SET "searching="` line. Searching will then never be reset, so each line in each file is reported.

If you want some other combination, please clarify.

I have absolutely no idea whatever what you mean by "marking" a line.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, findstr can't accept too long lines to process. I already used another solution, but thank you too, I'll learn from that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF & setlocal
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%i in ('set "$" 2^>nul') do set "%%i="

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
 for /f %%b in ('find /v /c "" ^<"%%a"') do echo(%%b lines in %%a.
 set /a counter=0, files+=1
 for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b in ("%%~a") do (
    set /a counter+=1, total+=1
    set "line=%%b"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if not defined $!line! set "$!line!=%%a=!counter!=!line!"
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('set "$" 2^>nul') do (if "!"=="" endlocal)& set "%%i"
    )
)
echo(%total% lines in %files% files.
for /f "delims=" %%a in (a) do set "#%%a=%%a"
for /f "tokens=2,3*delims==:" %%i in ('set "$" 2^>nul') do (
    if defined #%%k echo("%%k" found in %%i at line %%j.
)
```

Script can handle `!&<>|%`, but not `=`.